# How to set initial value based on current model instance

Tags: django, forms, django-models, django-forms

I am trying to create an edit form to edit current objects using Django. I am having trouble trying to get the current id of the object in order to set the initial value to the current values of the object.

I want to create an edit form that will already show the current data before the user edits a field. How do I go about doing this?

Thanks.

my forms.py:

```
class AddfooditemForm(forms.Form):
    quantity = forms.CharField(label="Quantity")
    price_per_pound = forms.CharField(label="price_per_pound")
    expiration_date = forms.CharField(label="expiration_date")
    price_per_item = forms.CharField(label="price_per_item")


class AddNonFooditemForm(forms.Form):
    quantity = forms.CharField(label="Quantity")
    price_per_item = forms.CharField(label="price_per_item")


class EditfooditemForm(ModelForm):
    quantity = forms.CharField(label="Quantity")
    price_per_pound = forms.CharField(label="price_per_pound")
    expiration_date = forms.CharField(label="expiration_date")
    price_per_item = forms.CharField(label="price_per_item")

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(EditfooditemForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    class Meta:
        model = tasks
        fields = ['quantity', 'price_per_item', 'expiration_date', 'price_per_pound']


class Edit_non_food_itemForm(ModelForm):
    quantity = forms.CharField(label="Quantity")
    price_per_item = forms.CharField(label="price_per_item")

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Edit_non_food_itemForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    class Meta:
        model = tasks
        fields = ['quantity', 'price_per_item']
```

my views.py:

```
@csrf_exempt
def add_item(request):

    if request.method == 'POST' and 'add_food_form' in request.POST:
        add_food_form = AddfooditemForm(request.POST)
        if add_food_form.is_valid():
            # Cleaned_data
            input_type = 'food'
            quantity = add_food_form.cleaned_data['quantity']
            price_per_pound = add_food_form.cleaned_data['price_per_pound']
            expiration_date = add_food_form.cleaned_data['expiration_date']
            price_per_item = add_food_form.cleaned_data['price_per_item']
            foodDict = {'price_per_item': price_per_item,
                        'quantity': quantity,
                        'price_per_pound': price_per_pound,
                        'expiration_date': expiration_date}
            foodData = pickle.dumps(foodDict)
            item = items(input_type=input_type, foodData=foodData)
            item.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('backup_app.views.items_listing'))


    if request.method == 'POST' and 'add_non_food_form' in request.POST:
        add_non_food_form = AddNonFooditemForm(request.POST)
        if add_non_food_form.is_valid():
            # Cleaned_data
            input_type = 'non_food'
            quantity = add_non_food_form.cleaned_data['quantity']
            price_per_item = add_non_food_form.cleaned_data['price_per_item']
            non_foodDict = {'quantity': quantity,
                            'price_per_item': price_per_item}
            non_foodData = pickle.dumps(non_foodDict)
            item = items(input_type=input_type, non_foodData=non_foodData)
            item.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('backup_app.views.items_listing'))

    else:

        'add_food_form': AddfooditemForm()
        'add_non_food_form': AddNonFooditemForm()

    return render(request, 'backup_app/items_listing.html', {'add_food_form': add_food_form,'add_non_food_form': add_non_food_form})

@csrf_exempt
def edit_item(request, item_id):
    item = items.objects.get(id=item_id)

    if request.method == 'POST' and 'edit_food_form' in request.POST:
        edit_food_form = EditfooditemForm(request.POST, instance=item)
        if edit_food_form.is_valid():
            print "valid"
            # Cleaned_data
            item.input_type = 'food'
            quantity = edit_food_form.cleaned_data['quantity']
            price_per_pound = edit_food_form.cleaned_data['price_per_pound']
            expiration_date = edit_food_form.cleaned_data['expiration_date']
            price_per_item = edit_food_form.cleaned_data['price_per_item']
            foodDict = {'price_per_item': price_per_item,
                        'quantity': quantity,
                        'price_per_pound': price_per_pound,
                        'expiration_date': expiration_date}
            item.foodData = pickle.dumps(foodDict)
            item.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('backup_app.views.items_listing'))

    if request.method == 'POST' and 'edit_non_food_form' in request.POST:
        edit_non_food_form = Edit_non_food_itemForm(request.POST, instance=item)
        if edit_non_food_form.is_valid():
            # Cleaned_data
            item.input_type = 'non_food'
            quantity = edit_non_food_form.cleaned_data['quantity']
            price_per_item = edit_non_food_form.cleaned_data['price_per_item']
            non_foodDict = {'quantity': quantity,
                            'price_per_item': price_per_item}

            item.non_foodData = pickle.dumps(non_foodDict)
            item.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('backup_app.views.items_listing'))
    else:
        context = {
            'edit_food_form': EditfooditemForm(instance=item),
            'edit_non_food_form': Edit_non_food_itemForm(instance=item)
        }
    return render(request, 'backup_app/items_listing.html', context)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

**forms.py:**

```
class ChangeForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ['field1', 'field2']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user = kwargs.pop('user')
        super(ChangeForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

**views.py:**

```
# To render multiple forms, repeat the process
def account_settings(request):
    change_form = ChangeForm(request.POST or None,
                             instance=request.user, user=request.user)
    change_form_2 = ChangeForm2(request.POST or None)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if change_form.is_valid():
            change_form.save()
        if change_form_2.is_valid():
            change_form_2.save()

    context = {
        'change_form': change_form,
        'change_form_2': change_form_2
    }
    return render(request, 'change_form.html', context)
```

That should give you the current data.

*Note: Change the attributes to your needs. If you post your code, I can help you with that. However, I don't know what you're working with, but the above should be a good template to follow.*

**EDIT:**

**views.py:**

```
@csrf_exempt
def add_item(request):
    add_food_form = AddfooditemForm(request.POST or None)
    add_non_food_form = AddNonFooditemForm(request.POST or None)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if add_food_form.is_valid():
            input_type = 'food'
            quantity = add_food_form.cleaned_data['quantity']
            price_per_pound = add_food_form.cleaned_data['price_per_pound']
            expiration_date = add_food_form.cleaned_data['expiration_date']
            price_per_item = add_food_form.cleaned_data['price_per_item']
            foodDict = {'price_per_item': price_per_item,
                        'quantity': quantity,
                        'price_per_pound': price_per_pound,
                        'expiration_date': expiration_date}
            foodData = pickle.dumps(foodDict)
            item = items(input_type=input_type, foodData=foodData)

        if add_non_food_form.is_valid():
            input_type = 'non_food'
            quantity = add_non_food_form.cleaned_data['quantity']
            price_per_item = add_non_food_form.cleaned_data['price_per_item']
            non_foodDict = {'quantity': quantity,
                            'price_per_item': price_per_item}
            non_foodData = pickle.dumps(non_foodDict)
            item = items(input_type=input_type, non_foodData=non_foodData)

        item.save()

        # This needs to be a url name
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('url_name_here'))

    context = {
        'add_food_form': add_food_form,
        'add_non_food_form': add_non_food_form
    }

    # Make this its own template
    return render(request, 'backup_app/items_add.html', context)


@csrf_exempt
def edit_item(request, item_id):
    item = items.objects.get(id=item_id)
    edit_food_form = EditfooditemForm(request.POST or None,
                                      instance=item)
    edit_non_food_form = Edit_non_food_itemForm(request.POST or None,
                                                instance=item)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if edit_food_form.is_valid():
            item.input_type = 'food'
            quantity = edit_food_form.cleaned_data['quantity']
            price_per_pound = edit_food_form.cleaned_data['price_per_pound']
            expiration_date = edit_food_form.cleaned_data['expiration_date']
            price_per_item = edit_food_form.cleaned_data['price_per_item']
            foodDict = {'price_per_item': price_per_item,
                        'quantity': quantity,
                        'price_per_pound': price_per_pound,
                        'expiration_date': expiration_date}
            item.foodData = pickle.dumps(foodDict)

        if edit_non_food_form.is_valid():
            item.input_type = 'non_food'
            quantity = edit_non_food_form.cleaned_data['quantity']
            price_per_item = edit_non_food_form.cleaned_data['price_per_item']
            non_foodDict = {'quantity': quantity,
                            'price_per_item': price_per_item}

            item.non_foodData = pickle.dumps(non_foodDict)

        item.save()

        # This needs to be a url name
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('url_name_here'))
    else:
        context = {
            'edit_food_form': EditfooditemForm(instance=item),
            'edit_non_food_form': Edit_non_food_itemForm(instance=item)
        }

    # Make this its own template
    return render(request, 'backup_app/items_edit.html', context)


def items_listing(request):
    # Any data you want to post about the listed items
    return render(request, 'backup_app/items_listing.html', {})
```

Comment: I don't have user atrributes, just task objects and their associated ids. So  would i need to include the part: "self.user = kwargs.pop('user')" ? Thanks for your help!

Comment: @shizznetz If you don't have user attributes, then no you shouldn't need it.

Comment: Am I not allowed to render to the same template twice? The edit form is not showing in the template I want it to.

Comment: @shizznetz I don't know how you're trying to render it, but it sounds like you only have one template on the view while trying to load it on two templates. Make a separate template variable with both templates, and then on the `return` make the `'change_form.html` `template` instead. That will read multiple templates.

Comment: So there is no way for me to render multiple forms on a single template ? Thanks and sorry for my newbie questions!

Comment: @shizznetz No worries. See my edit for how to render multiple forms on the same template.

Comment: Oops I meant that I already have an "add task" form before this that renders to the same template that I am trying to render to right now with the "edit" form. I was wondering if there's a way to do that.

Comment: @shizznetz To save ourselves a lot of time, could you please post your view as an edit to your original question?

Comment: @shizznetz Take a look at my edit section. I recommend doing something like that with your views.py

Comment: I did exactly that, but none of the templates are rendering the forms.

Comment: @shizznetz Did you create the templates/rename the one's I put in there for you as placeholders?

Comment: Yes. The templates renders everything EXCEPT the form itself. I made sure  that the form action matches the url i set in the url dispatcher and doubled check the names and variables.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85039/discussion-between-shizznetz-and-jape).

Comment: ok so i can view the add form and the edit form when i visit the actual link to the template. But the form does not render when i type : "{% include 'backup_app/edit_item.html' %}" or "{% include 'backup_app/add_item.html' %}"  in my items_listing template. Could it be this that's wrong?

Also, I am looping over all the existing objects and im placing my edit button based on that task_id in the row. So I can't render the edit form in a separate template since it will not grab the current task id.